# How to fix "unknown project ID (no ID found ) (Dispatcher API Error: 9)[CR][LF]" error?

Tags: captiva, captiva-designer

I am working on Captiva designer and my flow includes recognition project for Classification.
It was working all fine earlier, however I made one change recently. Just after that, the mentioned error started to show up. I have tried to keep the backup project back in location(which was working fine earlier), however now that also showing the same error now.

```
unknown project ID (no ID found ) (Dispatcher API Error: 9)[CR][LF]
```

[image]

How to get it fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the recognition project after you made the changes.
Without compiling, it might show you as saved, but when you deploy the flow, it might cause the project ID issue. Usually this issue happens when you copy the recognition profile from other environment. So once you copy or modify the existing recognition project, you should go to recognition -> open your project -> compile it and then map it with the flow, using classification setup.